# search through nested list in scheme to find a number

Tags: scheme

How would I search through the nested list to find a certain number?

For example, the list is:

```
((1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (3 5) (4 5))
```

and I'm looking for 1.

Expected output:

```
(1 2)
```

since 1 is in the sub list (1 2).

Answer (score 1):

First of all create function to flatten list. Something like this:

```
> (flatten '((8) 4 ((7 4) 5) ((())) (((6))) 7 2 ()))
(8 4 7 4 5 6 7 2)
```

And then search your number in the ordinary list.

This quesion looks like the homework so try to develop this function on your own and if you can not do it - post your code here and I'll try to help you.

**Updated**

Ok. As I understand we need to create function which get the list of pairs and return another list of pairs, where first element of pair equal some number.

For example:

```
(define data '((1 2)(2 3)(3 4)(3 5)(4 5)))
(solution data 3)
-> '((3 4) (3 5))

(define data '((1 2)(2 3)(3 4)(3 5)(4 5)))
(solution data 1)
-> '((1 2))
```

In the other words we need to **filter** our list of pairs by some condition.  In the Scheme there is a [function to filter list](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=filter#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._filter%29%29).  It takes a list to filter and function to decide - to include or not the element of list in the result list.

So we need to create such function:

```
(define (check-pair num p)
  (cond 
    [(= (first p) num) #t]
    [else #f]))
```

This function get a pair (element of list), number  and decide - incude or not this pair to result list.  This function have 2 parameters, but the filter function require the function with only one parameter, so we rewrite our function such way:

```
(define (check-pair num)
  (lambda (p)
    (cond 
      [(= (first p) num) #t]
      [else #f])))
```

I have created function wich produce another function. It is [currying](http://www.engr.uconn.edu/~jeffm/Papers/curry.html).

So, we have all to create our solution:

```
(define (check-pair num)
  (lambda (p)
    (cond 
      [(= (first p) num) #t]
      [else #f])))

(define (solution list num)
  (local 
    ((define check-pair-by-num (check-pair num)))
    (filter check-pair-by-num list)))

(define data '((1 2)(2 3)(3 4)(3 5)(4 5)))

(solution data 1)
```

Comment: I have the function to flatten it but how but if I flatten the function how would I find out what the pair (1 2) because that is what I want to store that in the new list.

Comment: Well, please describe what is in and out parameters of function and give some examples of its usage.

Comment: (lst s)  
where lst would be  ((1 2)(2 3)(3 4)(3 5)(4 5)) and s would be 1
I want to simply find the sub-list that would have 1 since its (1 2), I want to store this in the new list

Comment: Okay, I understand the flattening part. I made the flatten function and ran it on the list above which is the following: ((1 2)(2 3)(3 4)(3 5)(4 5))), I get the following list: (1 2 2 3 3 4 3 5 4 5), now if i were to search through this for 1, how would I store that number and the number next to it

Answer (score 0):

Flattening isn't the approach I'd prefer here, but that doesn't mean it's incorrect.  Here's an alternative:

```
    (define (solve lst num)
      (cond 
        [(null? lst) null]
        [(cons? (first lst)) (solve (first lst) num)]
        [(member num lst) (cons lst (solve (rest lst) num))]
        [#t (solve (rest lst) num)]))
```

This just recursively deals with nested listing as needed, so I prefer it a little bit stylistically. In addition, the call to `member` can be replaced with `check-pair` from above, but member will let you grab values from cdrs as well as cars, if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` to select a member of a list meeting a condition:

```
(find contains-1? '((1 2)(2 3)(3 4)(5 6)))
```

How to implement `contains-1?`  Hint: consider the `member` function:

```
(member 1 '(1 2)) => #t
(member 1 '(3 4)) => #f
```